# Laravel: Call to a member function getParameter() on a non-object

Tags: php, parameters, request, laravel-5

In the AppServiceProvider I want to set an object into the IoC container like:

```
$organisation = OrganisationHelper::getOrganisationBySlug();
$this->app->instance('Organisation', $organisation);
```

Inside OrganisationHelper I have the following code:

```
$slug = \App::make('request')->route()->getParameter('organisation');
return Organisation::select('id', 'name', 'slug')->where('slug', '=', $slug)->first();
```

The error I'm getting is:
**Call to a member function getParameter() on a non-object**

It's probably because the router has not been dispatched yet, but I don't know how to fix this or get the route parameter in any other way.

Any suggestions on how to resolve the route here?

Comment: Are you sure if route() is a function and not an attribute (i.e. route instead of route()) ? Could you join a var_dump of route (or route(), whichever the right one is) in that case ?

Comment: I think it's both, but both return null. If I dump \App::make('request') it shows a list with all kinds of things. But everything is null in here.